# gpointer cast to gint * causes segmentation fault - why?

Tags: c, pointers, glib

I'm trying to learn using void pointers in C. Here's a code I've written using GLib:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int
main (void)
{
  GList *l = NULL;
  l = g_list_append (l, GINT_TO_POINTER (1));
  l = g_list_append (l, GINT_TO_POINTER (2));
  l = g_list_append (l, GINT_TO_POINTER (3));
  GList *l1 = g_list_nth (l, 1);
  gpointer snd_element = (l1->data);
  gint *digit = snd_element;
  gint forty_two = 40;
  forty_two = forty_two + *digit;
  printf ("%d\n", forty_two);

  return 0;
}
```

The behaviour I expect from this program would be to print 42. Unfortunately running it causes segmentation fault. Why?

Comment: Why don't you check `l1` and `digit` for NULL before using them?

Comment: Because I'm trusting that `g_list_append` will actually add some data to l. That means l1 should be a GList * containing 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g_list_append` expects a pointer to the data you want to store to be passed. `GINT_TO_POINTER` simply converts the given integer to a pointer (i.e. it's basically `(gpointer)x`), hence the pointer isn't actually pointing at any valid data, it's just a number. After adding the data to the list, the pointers will have the value 1, 2 and 3.

Assuming that `g_list_nth` is successful, `l1->data` will be the *pointer* passed to `g_list_append` earlier. In this case, the value of the pointer will be 2 (**not** the value being pointed to). You then attempt to dereference this pointer, which will cause a segmentation fault.

Instead, just cast it straight back to an `int` and don't dereference to get the value back. You should probably use the provided reverse macro `GPOINTER_TO_INT` though, e.g.

```
gpointer snd_element = (l1->data);
gint digit = GPOINTER_TO_INT(snd_element); // Note I've removed the *...
gint forty_two = 40;
forty_two = forty_two + digit; // Note I've not attempted to dereference it
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
gpointer snd_element = (l1->data);
```

Makes `snd_element` contain the value `2` but converted to a pointer. This is very probably *not* a valid memory address for your process.

So this:

```
forty_two = forty_two + *digit;
```

which de-references `digit` causes undefined behavior.

You should do:

```
const int forty_two = 40 + GPOINTER_TO_INT(digit);
```

Comment: "why do you expect 40 + 1 to be 42?" -> `g_list_nth` takes a zero-based index ;)